# How do modern algebraists think about diagonal matrices?

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

Let $\mathbb{K}$ denote a field and $A$ denote a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra. Then given a $\mathbb{K}$-subalgebra $\Delta$ of $A$, I suppose it make sense to declare that $m \in A$ is $\Delta$-*diagonalizable* iff $m \in u^{-1}\Delta u$ for some unit $u \in A$. In the special case where $A$ is the matrix algebra $M_n \mathbb{K}$ and $\Delta$ is the subalgebra of diagonal matrices, this recovers the usual notion of diagonalizability. Alternatively, we might define that $m$ is $\Delta$-*diagonalizable* iff there exists an automorphism $\varphi$ of $A$ such that $\varphi(m) \in \Delta$. I think that since $\mathbb{K}$ was assumed a field, these definitions should be equivalent whenever $A$ is a matrix algebra. (Is this right?)

Anyway, this leaves open the question of how to think about the subalgebra of diagonal matrices.

> **Question.** How do modern algebraists think about diagonal matrices and/or the subalgebra of diagonal matrices?
>
> For example, a good answer might take any of the following perspectives.
>
> - The set $\Delta \subseteq A$ is uniquely defined, up to the action of automorphisms of $A$, by the following property...
> - From the viewpoint of diagonalizability, the important thing about $\Delta$ is that it satisfies the following axioms/conditions...
> - The subalgebra of diagonal matrices isn't really the right thing to be focusing on here; modern algebraists mostly focus on the concept [whatever]...
>
> This is not an exhaustive list of perspectives a good answer might take.

Comment: Modern (and old-fashioned) algebraists may think about diagonal matrices in terms of semisimple elements, algebraic groups etc.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of answer you're looking for. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, sure. I've added some material to the "Question" part of the question.

Comment: @rschwieb, fixed :)

Comment: @goblin As for the two definitions you proffered being the same on $M_n(\Bbb K)$, yes (the [Skolem-Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem))

Comment: @rschwieb, thanks. Honestly that theorem makes no sense to me as stated in the Wikipedia article. If $A$ is merely a ring, and hence, in particular, doesn't carry the structure of a $k$-algebra, how are we to speak of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $A \rightarrow B$?

Comment: @goblin Every ring is an algebra over its center, and every simple ring is a central simple ring over its center. The catch is that you've got to be interested in the maps that are linear over this center. I thought you would be willing to restrict your attention to $\Bbb K$ linear automorphisms of $M_n(\Bbb K)$, but if you aren't you're right, the theorem doesn't directly apply.

Comment: @rschwieb, I'm happy to restrict to $\mathbb{K}$-linear automorphisms, but have a look at the statement of that theorem on the wikipedia page. $A$ is an arbitrary ring, so its not a $k$-algebra in any meaningful sense...

Comment: @goblin Of course. My comment above about the N-S theorem specified $M_n(\Bbb K)$ only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not $100\%$ I'm the right person to speak for "modern algebraists," but here's some thoughts.

Dietrich mentions semisimple elements in his comment: these generalize diagonalizeable operators to elements of an algebra in the presence of an algebra representation - either an associative algebra or alternatively a Lie algebra. Indeed, given such an element $a$ and a representation $(\rho,V)$, with a vector space $V$ over $K$, we can make $V$ into a $K[T]$-module (where $K[T]$ is the usual polynomial ring) by making $T$ act by $\rho(a)$. Then $a\in A$ is semisimple if $V$ is semisimple as a $K[T]$-module.

By the fundamental theorem of finitely-generated modules over PIDs, our $K[T]$-module $V$ decomposes as $\bigoplus K[T]/f(T)^e$ where the $f$s are irreducible factors of $\rho(a)$'s characteristic polynomial in $K[T]$. These summands correspond to blocks in $\rho(a)$'s Frobenius normal form. The summands $K[T]/f(T)^e$ are indecomposable, but only simple when $e=1$. If $K$ is algebraically closed, the irreducible polynomials in $K[T]$ are linear, so semisimplicity of $a$ is equivalent to the fact $V\cong \bigoplus K[T]/(T-\lambda)$ which means $\rho(a)$ is equivalent to ${\rm diag}(\lambda)$. This recovers the usual understanding of diagonalizable.

I believe $a$ may be called semisimple if it so in the regular representation, and that this implies $\rho(a)$ is semisimple for any representation $\rho$, but my memory is hazy.

So semisimple captures the idea of *diagonalizability*, which is being diagonal with respect to *some* decomposition of the space. More generally we can say that if $A$ acts on $V$ then $a\in A$ acts diagonally with respect to a decomposition $V=\bigoplus V_i$ if we can write $\rho(a)=\bigoplus_i\rho(a)_i$. This could potentially mean nondiagonalizable matrices are in fact diagonal with respect to certain decompositions. Indeed, for any endomorphism there is decomposition of $V$ that cannot be refined further under which this is true: one takes the summands of $V$ that correspond to the factors $K[T]/f(T)^e$ in the decomposition guaranteed by the fundamental theorem and then a matrix will act by the blocks of the Frobenius normal form on each summand of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the following theorem, which seems relevant:

> For each $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $A$, there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to which $A$ is diagonal. More explicitly: for each symmetric real matrix $A,$ there exists a real orthonormal matrix $Q$ such that $Q^\top A Q$ is diagonal.